# PERL Regex help matching a string in a field

Tags: regex, perl

I currently have a field that looks like this.

`item description is blah ablha blabh albhalbh  #thisisitemnumber x/skid)`

I am trying to extract the `#thisisitemnumber` portion.  I currently have this:

`'/(#.*\S)/'`

But using that I get everything after the "#" even the whitespace. 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, because `.*` gobbles up **everything** after the `#` up to a final `\S` (which would be the `")"` of `"skid)"` in your case). Try `/(#\S+)/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are matching any char `.` any number of times `*` until non-space `\S`. This isn't really what you want. Also, since `*` is greedy it scoops up everything up to the *last* non-space in the string.

You want non-space one or more times:

```
/(#\S+)/;
```

This presumes that there should be *something* after `#`, thus the `+`

Comment: Ok, I'm still having some trouble, if I do  `'/(#\S+)/'` I'm not getting anything.  If I do `'/(#\S*)/'`  I am only getting the "#" sign.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlliDeacon  Try this:     `perl -wE '$str = "item description is blah ablha blabh albhalbh #thisisitemnumber x/skid)"; ($m) = $str =~ /(#\S+)/; say $m'`.   It prints `#thisisitemnumber` for me.

Comment: @AlliDeacon Is `#thisisitemnumber` your actual input? Not something like `# 12.34`? The name suggests it is a **number**. Please show a real (non-simplified) example.

Comment: @AlliDeacon  I think it would have to do with what exact strings you're feeding it.  What you state would happen if you give it a string without anything after `#`, for example.  If the problem persists please post typical input that you may need to deal with. The question as it stands implies that your input has `#something `.  If input can be different we need to know that.

Comment: @AlliDeacon  If you can have strings ending with `#` or having a space after it  (like `# other...`) then you have a design decision to make.  Either have _nothing_ captured (code as it stands), or capture `#` alone -- for this change the `+` to `*`.  If you want to pick up the number even if there is a space in there, like in `# 13`, then the regex would have to be modified to allow an optional single (stretch of) space after `#`, for example.

Comment: @PerlDog I had an issue within my Reporting Tool, and needed to include '%' for "LIKE", or include all characters but Space, not using \S or \s.  Thank you for your input, it was very helpful, I apologize for my lack of response to comments after.

Comment: @zdim Your solution worked perfectly, but not inside my reporting tool.  I needed to include "%"  for like, but ended up just including all characters.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlliDeacon  Thanks for the response -- I don't understand what `"%" for like` means.  Can you explain, maybe we can adjust this so to work for that case as well?  I apologize if it is something obvious that I am not seeing.  I also don't understand your previous comment -- do you need to do this without using `\S` and `\s` for some reason?

Comment: @zdim using the "%" in the beginning and end of the expression equal "LIKE" in this particular tool.  If I had used that initially the \S and \s would have worked like this: `like(@[Item Description], '%/(#\S+)/%')`  It was a solution I didn't think of until the Software Support suggested it.